# ASP MVC RedirectToAction passing an array of objects without using ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, redirecttoaction

I have the following method

```
 public ActionResult Search(FormCollection form)
    {
         .......
        Publication[] publicationsResult = server.SearchLibrary(this.getSession(), sq);

        return RedirectToAction("BookListing", new { publications = publicationsResult });
    }
```

Which gets a list of publications from the server and stores it in an array of type Publication.

I would like to show the results in another page, thus I redirected to the following method:

```
public ActionResult BookListing(Publication[] publications)
    {
        Publication[] p = publications;
        return View(publications);
    }
```

And I also have the following Routes defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Library", action = "Search", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "PublicationListing", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{publications}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Library", action = "BookListing", publications = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

When in *Search* the publications array is populated with over 13000 objects, however when I redirect to *BookListing* null is passed.

Is there a way to pass an array of objects from one action method to another using RedirectToAction?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to redirect the user? You could just return the BookListing view from the Search action.

Comment: Ideally yes, as I would like the user to be able to bookmark the url

Comment: You are essentially trying to convert an entire array into something that can be passed on the URL. This isn't going to work as you only have 256 characters in the URL for a start.

Comment: You could save the search in the database and return the user an ID for that search so they can bookmark the results or place the search parameters into the request /Search?title=Test&author=John etc. That sort of thing - that way they can bookmark that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have the TempData collection. This is persisted between the action redirects for a single request and so provides you with storage for anything like this...

Comment: I am looking for another way apart from TempData. But to clarify, the TempData dictionary will hold that data for only one redirect?

Comment: Correct - temp data persists only during the request.